# Restrict robot access for (specific) query string (parameter) values?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Using robot.txt is it possible to restrict robot access for (specific) query string (parameter) values?

ie

```
http://www.url.com/default.aspx  #allow
http://www.url.com/default.aspx?id=6  #allow
http://www.url.com/default.aspx?id=7  #disallow
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /default.aspx?id=7  # disallow
Disallow: /default.aspx?id=9  # disallow
Disallow: /default.aspx?id=33 # disallow

etc...
```

You only need to specify the url's that are disallowed. Everything else is allowed by default.

Comment: Thanks I just wasn't sure about this, that's what I thought :D

Answer (score 0):

Can just the query variable defined such as

Disallow: /default.aspx?id=*

or better still

Disallow: /*?id=*